# What is the difference between V1 and v2 of google Cloud Speech-to-Text

Tags: speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech, google-speech-to-text-api

My code project framework is springboot+maven, version is

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-speech</artifactId>
            <version>1.24.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I used 2.3.0, the code gave me an error.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-speech</artifactId>
<!--            <version>1.24.3</version>-->
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "pool-4-thread-1" Exception in thread "pool-3-thread-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder: method <init>()V not found
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.<init>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:200)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.forTarget(NettyChannelBuilder.java:169)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(NettyChannelBuilder.java:152)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider.builderForAddress(NettyChannelProvider.java:38)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider.builderForAddress(NettyChannelProvider.java:24)
    at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:39)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:350)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.<init>(ChannelPool.java:105)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:83)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:236)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:230)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:201)
    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.stub.GrpcSpeechStub.create(GrpcSpeechStub.java:95)
    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.stub.SpeechStubSettings.createStub(SpeechStubSettings.java:133)
    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.SpeechClient.<init>(SpeechClient.java:134)
    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.SpeechClient.create(SpeechClient.java:116)
    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.SpeechClient.create(SpeechClient.java:108)
    at com.duplicall.ibaeonline.EngineClients.google.InfiniteStreamRecognize.infiniteStreamingRecognize(InfiniteStreamRecognize.java:95)
    at com.duplicall.ibaeonline.EngineClients.google.InfiniteStreamRecognize.lambda$StartTrans$0(InfiniteStreamRecognize.java:291)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder: method <init>()V not found
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.<init>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:200)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.forTarget(NettyChannelBuilder.java:169)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(NettyChannelBuilder.java:152)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider.builderForAddress(NettyChannelProvider.java:38)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider.builderForAddress(NettyChannelProvider.java:24)
    at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:39)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:350)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.<init>(ChannelPool.java:105)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:83)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:236)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:230)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:201)
    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.stub.GrpcSpeechStub.create(GrpcSpeechStub.java:95)
    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.stub.SpeechStubSettings.createStub(SpeechStubSettings.java:133)
    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.SpeechClient.<init>(SpeechClient.java:134)
    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.SpeechClient.create(SpeechClient.java:116)
    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.SpeechClient.create(SpeechClient.java:108)
    at com.duplicall.ibaeonline.EngineClients.google.InfiniteStreamRecognize.infiniteStreamingRecognize(InfiniteStreamRecognize.java:95)
    at com.duplicall.ibaeonline.EngineClients.google.InfiniteStreamRecognize.lambda$StartTrans$0(InfiniteStreamRecognize.java:291)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I didn't know the difference between V1 and V2. I thought that the google-cloud-speech version upgrade should be backward compatible. Please comment if you are familiar with the product

Comment: It's generally expected that changing Major release numbers may contain some breaking changes (through refactoring, deprecated functions etc.). Minor releases on the other hand would normally be expected to be backwards compatible.